# connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am new to postgres and psql. Yesterday i am working with postgres it's working but today morning it's not working it shows error when i run the command "sudo -i -u Postgres" I'm into Postgres after I typing "psql" it shows error like "connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?" what to do now because I have 6 laks records inside my postgress how to clear this error . plz someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your database is not running, make sure that your database server is running by querying
ps -ef | grep postgres

If it is not running try to start it with pg_ctl command and check.

I hope it helps